# Optimized c++ code with Time complexity as O(n2) and space complexity as O(1) for following input

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

array i/p : 1 0 0 2 1 0 2 1

Note:There are only 3 numbers i.e 0,1,2.
one function we have to use is: SWAP(arr,index1,index2)
Method to implement is:
void sort(int arr[], int length)

Expected o/p: 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2

Answer (score 1):

There are many algorithms to sort an array of numbers. The simplest of all - the bubble sort has time complexity of O(n2) and space complexity of O(1).

More O(n2) sorting algorithms : selection sort and insertion sort.

However, there are better algorithms that can achieve a time complexity of O(n.logn) - Merge sort, Quick sort, etc.

What do you mean by there are only 3 numbers : 0,1,2.
If the input is fixed and we know that there are only going to be these 3 numbers, then the easiest way to sort is to count the number of occurrences of each of these numbers. For this example :

`occurrences[0] = 3;
occurrences[1] = 3;
occurrences[2] = 2;`

Then you could simply write into the output array, each number repeated the number of times found in occurrences[].
Time Complexity of this solution : O(m)
Space Complexity of this solution : O(m)
Important thing to note here is 'm' is the number of possible numbers, so here m = 3 and NOT the number of integers in the input array - which we called 'n'.